# How do I stop cat hair and dander form leaving my bedroom and bathroom and going into the rest of the house?

Tags: cats, allergies

I really want an indoor cat that I can keep in my room and bathroom and make ledges on the wall for the cat to run along and play and I will have a catio (an outdoor enclosed patio for cats), it will be in my yard along the side of the house, but my dad and brother are allergic to cats. My dad said that I can have a cat if I can somehow make sure no cat hair or dander leaves my room and bathroom and goes into the rest of the house. What can I do to keep  the cat hair and dander from leaving my bedroom and bathroom and then going into the rest of my house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Manage the Hair Problem Regularly**
While I think you'll find it nigh impossible to completely eradicate the hair, there are a few of things that you could do to significantly cut down on the problem.

1. **Vacuum/Sweep Daily**: This should cut down on the amount of hair present in the rooms that you are traveling from.
2. **Brush your Cat Daily**: This will reduce the amount of hair that your cat sheds be preemptively handling it. Also, many cats love being brushed!
3. **Lint Roll Yourself Whenever Leaving the Cat Zone**: This last measure prevents you accidentally transporting any hair that you may have missed with the previous two steps out of the cat zone.

Comment: I'll ask my dad if i can get a cat now!! Thank you for the information, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I 100% agree with Cricket that it's practically impossible to stop the cat fur. For example, even when I brush the cat I can't brush her entire body, and that's when she wants to sit still enough. The unbrushed hair will shed and float around the house.

#### Experience

It's really commendable that you are doing research. I strongly recommend learning by doing, and before making the commitment. Some options:

- Do you have a local animal shelter that needs volunteers?
- Can you work at a cat boarding job? I found the help was staffed by students studying to be veterinarians and techs.
- Become a foster home to cats (at shelters/rescues). This is very dangerous because many graduate to ***adopt their foster*** cat (I'm guilty).

#### More ways to manage

1. Wear "smock" layer over your clothing while you are in contact
2. Separate laundry; I know pet owners with extra laundry machines which they dedicate to pet laundry. Also, got a helpful tip from cat boarding tech about cat hair magnets (rubber ball pet toys) to wash with the clothes that can collect the hair off the fabric.
3. Security door like vestibule or
   [mantrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantrap_(access_control)).
   I observed these spaces also at the cat boarding house. It serves as a precaution for cats dashing through doors. It can be an extra chance to catch and confine the stray fur. Pause here to use the lint roller, remove your smock layer, and toss into laundry machine.